# Z-Index is not working even if set to maximum limit

Tags: html, css

The issue is in this link 
http://www.accept.eu.kia.com/us/models/kia-sorento-2014/

If you can scroll to just above end of the page, there is a red button 'Configure', which creates a lightbox popup which is hiding behind a div. I cannot bring this popup over it even though its having a greater z-index. There is another 'configure' button just below a 360 degree rotatable car which is working fine.

Am I missing something obvious

Comment: Is the lightbox positioned as absolute, static or relative? Also, what's the parent z-index? A child element can never have a higher z-index than its parent element, because the scope of the z-index is the parent element. It's not global. I suggest this read: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/.

Comment: The lightbox is fixed. I have'nt set any specifix z-index to parent. let me check the link. Thanks

Comment: Z-index is very nasty. ;)

Comment: this is not complete answer but i think i can help to get the solutions on 2nd configure button case the popup div with @class = mainLayer visualizerConfigurator is display:none. which i think need to be block but the problem in this is the popup div under overlay (not able to figured out from where is coming) is showing . i think if you able to figured out hte reason of that div then it will resolve your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
.lightBoxOverlay{
 z-index : 10001  //Change this to 0
}
```

For me changes will be in `product.css:13172`

I think the `z-index` of the div having black overlay effect is greater then your popup div that is why it is showing behind.

Feel free to ask any further question

**Update 1**

Issue is not with `z-index` actually your popup div is not getting `display:block` it is still `display:none` after clicking **configure** button Can you just have a look in code causing that `display:none` or `block` to your popup.

Comment: Thanks, but lightBoxOverlay is actually needed to be on top of all elements and the PopUp should be over that. Popup got a z-index of 10002

Comment: hi @Nancy can you please provide me the line number for style for your popup actually iam not able to track it.So that i can look into it

Answer (score 0):

class 'slick-list draggable' should have z-index greater than lightbox wrapper.